# TLinkLabel background on a TPageControl

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I am trying to use a TLinkLabel on a TPageControl, and I can't find a way to make it use it's parent's background.

```
// Image removed because the website doesn't exist any more 
// and I can't find it anywhere... Sorry.
```

As you can see, the parent tab sheet's lovely gradient is not preserved behind the link text.

I would like the functionality of having multiple links in a flowing block of text (the functionality that TLinkLabel provides) *and* have the background of the parent showing behind the text.

TLinkLabel does not have a ParentBackground property. I have tried creating a derived class that adds csParentBackground to the control style, to no avail:

```
TMyLinkLabel = class (TLinkLabel)
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
end;

...

constructor TMyLinkLabel.Create(AOwner: TComponent); 
begin
  inherited;
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle - [csOpaque] + [csParentBackground]
end;
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is the text static or will it change after compile time?

Comment: The image URL is broken.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for letting me know... Wish I could find the image, and I'd upload it somewhere more permanent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nat, you are nearly there with your changes to the `ControlStyle` of the `TLinkLabel`. What you have to do in addition is to make sure that the parent of the standard Windows static control (that's what the `TLinkLabel` is) handles the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message correctly.

The VCL has a nice redirection mechanism to let controls handle messages that are sent as notifications to their parent windows for themselves. Making use of this a completely self-contained transparent link label can be created:

```
type
  TTransparentLinkLabel = class(TLinkLabel)
  private
    procedure CNCtlColorStatic(var AMsg: TWMCtlColorStatic);
      message CN_CTLCOLORSTATIC;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

constructor TTransparentLinkLabel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle - [csOpaque] + [csParentBackground];
end;

procedure TTransparentLinkLabel.CNCtlColorStatic(var AMsg: TWMCtlColorStatic);
begin
  SetBkMode(AMsg.ChildDC, TRANSPARENT);
  AMsg.Result := GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
end;
```

Comment: +1 looks like a great solution, I see no problems, but can't test as I only have D2006 on the machine I'm traveling with.  Have you tested this in RAD2009 or 2010?  A screen shot to compare with Nat's?

Comment: Tested with Delphi 2009, screen shot (Windows XP, olive colour scheme) at http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/5849/tranparentlinklabel2.png - for illustration only every second label is a `TTransparentLinkLabel`.

Comment: That's the answer! :) I'd managed to get about 80% there on Friday (see comment to Rob Kennedy's post where I mentioned 'research'). Thank you!

Comment: @Nat I think the solution needs a little elaboration. The code in you `CNCtlColorStatic` should only be called when `ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled`, otherwise call `inherited`.  Also, I think there ought to be a call to `ThemeServices.DrawParentBackground(Handle, Message.ChildDC, nil, False);` after `SetBkMode`.  In other words you do the same as `TCustomStaticText` does.

Answer (score 4):

Normally I hate it when people offer a third-party component as an answer, but I'll mention the TMS THTMLabel as an alternative for what you want to do. It has the Transparent property of the TLabel, and allows you to use HTML as the caption, and so you can do multiple links as per your example.

Comment: Thanks for that. Had seen that component before, but don't have any dollars to spend at the moment. The budget has been depleted by the purchase of Delphi 2010. :)

Answer (score 3):

The `csParentBackground` and `csOpaque` styles both require cooperation from other parts of the control's code. Merely setting them wouldn't have much effect; if it did, then the control would probably have a public `Transparent` property already.

You can look at `TCustomLabel.Paint` to see how it respects the `csOpaque` style. It checks for that style by reading its `Transparent` property before it paints its background:

```
if not Transparent then
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Color := Self.Color;
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  FillRect(ClientRect);
end;
```

The `csParentBackground` style has no effect on `TCustomLabel` because that style only affects windowed controls; `TCustomLabel` descends from `TGraphicControl`, not `TWinControl`.

I don't have `TLinkLabel`, so I can't look at its source code to find out what it would need to change. If it's a `TGraphicControl` descendant, then it would need to include code like I showed above from `TCustomLabel`. If it descends from `TWinControl`, then I'd adapt code from `TCustomStaticText` instead. That's a little more complicated; it calls `DrawParentBackground` in response to the `cn_CtlColorStatic` notification message. It also doesn't paint itself in Delphi code. The control is a wrapper for the Win32 "static" control type.

`TLinkLabel` evidently paints its background unconditionally. To fix this, you'll need to override the `Paint` method. *Removing* functionality (background-painting, in this case) is hard to do with the traditional way of overriding virtual methods because you won't be able to call the inherited method to get all the text painted. Instead, You'll probably have to copy and paste the base class's implementation and then add the conditional parts in the middle somewhere.

Comment: I have been doing a lot of investigation into this over night... By default, setting csParentBackground *does* actually do something. It will call the theme services to draw the backgrounnd in response to WM_ERASEBACKGND (dependant on certain settings). This is actually being done... I think the control is then painting over it, but I need to do more research. I will update the question on Monday (it's the weekend down here in OZ, and I have shows to light!).

Comment: Right. That's what I meant by cooperation from the control — even if `csParentBackground` is set, the control has to cooperate by *not* painting over it.

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is to create helper class under implementation

```
type
  TLinkLabelHelper = class helper for TLinkLabel
  public
    procedure Add(const aBGColor: TColor; const S: string);
  end;

procedure TLinkLabelHelper.Add(const aBGColor: TColor; const S: string);
begin
  Color := aBGColor;
  Caption := S;
end;
```

Then, I create a public

```
procedure AfterConstruction; override;

procedure Form_A.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  LinkLabel1.Add(Self.Color, 'Hello World');
end;
```

Hope this works.

Comment: No, it won't work, as a themed background can be something different than a single colour-filled area. The page control in the question for example has a gradient background. The correct solution needs to make the link label not paint its own background / make it transparent, so that the parent background shines through.

Comment: mghie is correct. I don't want to change the background *color*, I want the parent control's background *theme* behind the label text.

Answer (score 0):

My advice: use simple TLabel. TLabel has a property named Transparent - this is what you need. Set your TLabels cursor to crHandPoint (AFAIR this is the link cursor), set font to blue underline, and write OnClick event handler, that will open web browser to navigate to the pointed url.
You can even have one default event handler.

```
procedure OnClickOnMyLinkTLabels(Sender : TObject);
var
  Address : string;
begin
  if NOT (Sender is TLabel) then Exit;
  Address := (Sender as TLabel).Caption;
  ShellExecute(self.WindowHandle,'open',PChar(Address),nil,nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

**Edit**:

If you do not want to have address in your caption, you can use Tag property to retrieve address and set caption to whatever you want:

```
procedure OnClickOnMyLinkTLabels(Sender : TObject);
var
  Address : string;
begin
  if NOT (Sender is TLabel) then Exit;
  Address :=  GetAddresByTag( (Sender as TLabel).Tag );
  ShellExecute(self.WindowHandle,'open',PChar(Address),nil,nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

How you will implement GetAddresByTag is your choice. The most simple one is use an array of strings:

```
//in your form defintion
   private
     FAddresses : array of string;

function GetAddresByTag(id : integer): string;
begin
  if (i<Low(FAddresses)) OR (I> High(FAddresses)) then
    raise EXception.Create('wrong id sent!');
  Result:= FAddresses[id];
end;
```

Comment: :) Great idea. But I would like to have the link in the middle of the text. I'll clarify my example a little to show what I mean.

Comment: @smok1: ummm... so you are proposing that I manually position the labels in amongst the text at design time? I am setting the text at runtime, and could be a verity of different strings with links in them (not web addresses, not that it matters).

Comment: @smok1: oh, and the form is resizable, so the text (and links) have to flow... Not easily doable with lots of TLabels on your form.

Comment: No. You should use Tag property of those controls. This is almost everything you have to do in designtime. The rest can be done in a runtime. You can even have and XML file and read appropriate address when needed.

Comment: Oh, and if you do not want to use Tag property, you can even use Name property of a control... So there are a lot of possible ways to get the address when you have an instance of TLabel - what you choose is your decision.

Comment: Ah, I see, there is some confusion here... Take a look at my new example. I would like to have multiple clickable areas/links in *one* label, not have multiple labels with multiple links.

Comment: Hmmm... I think OnMouseDown event has some X and Y coordinates, so you could use them to detect in which link user has clicked. But this is going to be a bit hardcore coding...

Comment: Indeed... I would need to draw the label myself, including changing the font style to underlined for each link, manage wrapping, hit test the mouse clicks etc. Not a trivial bit of coding. Thanks for your suggestions though. :)

Comment: This is a very bad idea, since a `TLabel` cannot receive keyboard focus, being a graphic control and not a windowed control. Hence, you will not be able to use the hyperlink using the keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

If your text is static, then you can still do this using labels.  Lay out your entire text block INCLUDING the words you want as links.  Set the label as transparent.  Next, drop separate label components (also set to transparent) that will be the link.  Change the color to clNavy, font style to fsunderline and the cursor to crHand.  Then position the label OVER the existing text.  Then write a onClick handler for each "link" label to perform your hot link.

While this is not optimal, it does work as long as you don't want to bold the text and are willing to keep the text the same font size.  Of course this doesn't work so well if the block is dynamic, as you would have to calculate the position of the link labels in code, which is fairly complicated if you are using wordwrap.  If not, you can use the canvas.textwidth and canvas.textheight methods to determine the necessary offset positions for your link labels.

Comment: Beware: When ClearType or ordinary antialiasing is in effect, the top label won't completely cover the bottom label's text. The bottom label will "bleed through," affecting the color of the top text.

Comment: Unfortunatly, in my real world code, the text is wrapping, and it's on a resizable form, so it has to flow... Thanks for your suggestion.